# Why are Duplicates not being filtered out

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on some practice interview Questions and am struggling with this:

You are working with a company that sells goods to customers, and they'd like to keep track
of the unique items each customer has bought. The database is composed of two tables:
Customers and Orders. The two table schemas are given below. We want to know what
unique items were purchased by a specific customer, Wilbur, and when they were
purchased. What is the correct query that returns the customer first name, item
purchased, and purchase date with recent purchases first?
Tables: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0ydy.jpg

My answer so far is

However I am getting an incorrect message as its Printing `wilbur,oranges,2019-06-10`
and `wilbur,oranges,2018-06-10` instead of just the one with the more recent date. Please see the picture for the two tables referenced by the question. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question, add table description and some data in text format not images and what is your expected result ?

Comment: So exactly where does your query implement *the one with the more recent date*? The two rows of data are distinct, therefore both are included. Also please don't link to external [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) which not everyone can view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between the `where` clause and `ORDER BY`, try:

```
GROUP BY FirstName, Item
```

And to get the most recent date, select `MAX(PurchaseDate)`.

Answer (score 0):

The query you are looking for is as follows.

This uses `group by` to indicate which columns should be *grouped* together, and for the column that's not grouped, how to choose which value of many to use, in this case the `max` value.

Note also the use of explicit, clear, SQL-92 modern *join syntax* and meaningful column aliases to show which table each column originates from. `Distinct` is not needed since each group is already unique.

```
Select c.FirstName, o.Item, Max(o.PurchaseDate) PurchaseDate
from Customers c
join Orders o on o.PersonId=p.PersonId
where c.FirstName = 'Wilbur'
group by c.firstName, o.Item
order by Max(o.PurchaseDate) desc;
```